# Doob-Meyer decomposition for a biased compound Poisson process?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, martingales

Consider the compound Poisson process:

$$X(t)=\sum_{i=1}^{N(t)}D_i$$

where $N(t)$ is a Poisson process and $D_i$ is a random integer jump. Let us even reduce to the case of jumps $\pm 1$ with probability of positive jump $p>0.5$.

Since the jump distribution is asymmetric, it is a submartingale and thus it has a Doob-Meyer decomposition.

How can this decomposition be constructed explicitly?
It appears [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2546325/doob-meyer-decomposition-for-exponentials) that the Ito formula could be a useful tool.
Is the predictable part trivial in this example? What about more general continuous-time random walks?

Comment: Hint: If $\lambda$ is the rate of the Poisson process, then $X(t) -\lambda t(2p-1)$ is a martingale.

Comment: Ok I see, so the predictable process is proportional to time / it is trivial here, thank you. What about a general compound Poisson process or even a continuons time random walk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the specific coefficient $\lambda(2p-1)$, write down the infinitesimal matrix $A$ for the continuous-time Markov chain $X(t)$, and then apply $A$ to the identity function $f(i)=i$ (thought of as a column vector); call the resulting function $g:=Af$. (In this specific case, $g$ is the constant function with constant value $\lambda(2p-1)$.) Then $X(t) -\int_0^t g(X(s))\,ds$ is a martingale. The same device works for more general $f$ and more general continuous-time Markov chains, of which a compound Poisson process is a special case (for which $g$ is again constant).